# Auto update quantity from one sheet to another

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, updates, equations

We have an Inventory list with columns for Brand, Product, Qty then the multiple prices columns.

We have a Sales sheet with columns for the Date, Product (which uses Data Validation for a drop down list which pulls up all of the products from the Products column in the Inventory Sheet), Type, Price, Qty, then Total Cost.

When an item is sold it is logged in the Sales sheet but we then have to go into the Inventory sheet and update the Qty there as well.

Is it possible to have the Qty in the Inventory automatically update when we log an item sold with the qty in the Sales sheet??

I have found this code but am having a hard time adjusting it to fit our sheets particularly, if at all possible.

```
=C2 + SUMIFS('Receiving Sheet'!QuantityColumn, 'Receiving Sheet'!ItemIDColumn, A2) - SUMIFS('Sales Sheet'!QuantityColumn, 'Sales Sheet'!ItemIDColumn, A2) Or… =LET(ItemID, A2, InitialQty, C2, ReceivedQty, SUMIFS('Receiving Sheet'!QuantityColumn, 'Receiving Sheet'!ItemIDColumn, ItemID), SoldQty, SUMIFS('Sales Sheet'!QuantityColumn, 'Sales Sheet'!ItemIDColumn, ItemID), NewQty, InitialQty + ReceivedQty - SoldQty, NewQty)
```

Inventory list image:
[image: Inventory list image]

Inventory Sales image:
[image: Inventory Sales image]

Comment: Based on your screenshots, you'll need VBA.

Comment: When working on multiple tables, you might consider using a relational database, rather than a spreadsheet, with its limitations. MS Office has Access, LibreOffice Base, and there are numerous other free and paid databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With just those two tables where the product name and qty are on the same line, it can be pretty easy to do. Here's a simplified version of your workbook, with tables labeled Sales and Inventory:

[image]

Your screenshot cut off some of the column headers, so here's how mine are set up:

- First, you need a **starting** quantity (InitialQty in your copied formula) in the Inventory table, or else there's nothing to subtract sales from
- [Optional] To sum together the quantities from Sales, use `SumIf()` like this formula (column F):

```
# Sum Qty from sales, where the product name in sales matches the inventory 
=SUMIF(A2:A5, D2, B2:B5)

# or with named ranges:
=SUMIF(Sales[SaleProduct],[@InvProduct],Sales[SaleQty])
```

- And to combine the starting quantity minus current (column G):

```
=(E2 - SUMIF(A2:A5, D2, B2:B5))

=([@QtyStart] - SUMIF(Sales[SaleProduct],[@InvProduct],Sales[SaleQty]))
```